# OpenFDA: Programmatic/Machine Readable Biologic License Application Data

Tags: openfda

Is there a way to programatically (or manually) download the biologic license applications data in a machine readable format?

Here is a PDF that at the bottom has the 2015 approvals, https://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/DevelopmentApprovalProcess/HowDrugsareDevelopedandApproved/DrugandBiologicApprovalReports/NDAandBLAApprovalReports/UCM486442.pdf
but I don't see those BLA applications in this data (link at bottom of page).
https://www.fda.gov/drugs/informationondrugs/ucm079750.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the Drugs@FDA dataset and was able to find the features the pdf contains. I just used a text editor and a search application but did not go into the semantics of the data.

With the `BLA NUMBER` or `APPLICATION NUMBER` (e.g. BLA 125504/0.0) serving as key you can get all your desired infos. However you need to strip down the prefix BLA and the suffix /0.0 to be able to do so.

Beginning with the file Applications.txt you can find the `ApplType` (BLA) and the Applicant in the field `SponsorName`.

Within Products.txt you can find the Proprietary Name and the Proper Name in the fields `DrugName` and `ActiveIngredient`. But be advised that there can be more than 1 product per `ApplNo` so you should probably use the product with the `ProductNo = 001`.

To get the Approval Date you have to take a look into Submissions.txt. There you should filter for `SubmissionType = ORIG` to find the data in the field `SubmissionStatusDate`. Also the Review Classification (whether S for Standard or P for Priority) is listed there in the field `ReviewPriority`.

The last piece of information (the O in Review Classification for Orphan Designation) can be retrived via SubmissionPropertyType.txt. There a record with the corrsponding `ApplNo` and `SubmissionType = ORIG` could be found labeling the `SubmissionPropertyTypeCode` as Orphan.

In summary the data is available in a relational nature. I think your best bet is to import the data and construct the records shown in the pdf by joining it together (e.g. by using a relational database and applying SQL). As i mentioned at the beginning i did not go into the semantics of the data so there is a good chance i missed something.

**Edit**

Here a little proof of concept in SQL
[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: from what URL did you download the data? Looks slightly different than mine.

Comment: I used the download link you provided. Yeah I  noticed that my result looks slightly different than the report you linked to your question. My answer is not a final solution but should guide in the right direction.